# How to make a system of diff. eq. independent of time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about the following bit:

[image]
I don't see how our system would become independent of time if we introduce $\tau$ and set $\dot\tau=1$? Also, I don't see why they speak of introducing a variable, while it looks like they substitute $t$ by $\tau$. We don’t have $\dot x=F(t,\tau,x)$, do we?

Comment: The goal is no to establish $\dot x=F(t,\tau,x)$, but on the opposite reduce to $\dot x=F(x)$. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to replace time, the independent variable $t$, by a dependent variable $\tau(t):=t$ (and of course $\dot\tau(t)=1$).

Then the system

$$\dot{\mathbb x}=f(t,\mathbb x)$$ becomes another system

$$\begin{align}\dot\tau&=1,\\\dot{\mathbb x}&=f(\tau,\mathbb x)\end{align}$$

or by forming the augmented vector $\mathbb x^\dagger=(\tau,\mathbb x)$, we have $$\dot{\mathbb x}^\dagger=f^\dagger(\mathbb x^\dagger)$$

where the *explicit* dependency on $t$ has disappeared.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't realise that $\tau$ is a function of time, but of course it is. Also, I didn't think we would introduce an augmented vector, but that makes sense for sure. Thanks a lot for clearing up the confusion:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solution of the system, which is equivalent to the time independent equation
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot{\tau}=1\\
\dot{x}=F(\tau,x)
\end{array}
\right.\iff\dot{X}=\Phi(X) \text{ (with }X=(\tau,x)),$$
then $x$ is a solution of the time dependent equation
$$\dot{x}=F(t,x).$$ Equivalently, a solution $x$ of the time dependent equation gives a solution of the independent one, namely $X=(t,x)$.